# Magento 2.1.3 Swagger and api error

Tags: magento2, api, import, rest-api, soap

Im using Magento 2.1.3 and PHP 7.0.8.

I would like to test some Magentos 2 import api.

When I'm trying to connect to swagger by http://localhost/swagger error 500 is received:
[image]

I'm also trying to connect to http://localhost/rest/default/schema?services=all
and return:
[image]

I am worried about that it doesn't works.
However I am able to connect via rest to eg. http://localhost/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token and get user token.

I also tried to install https://www.npmjs.com/package/magento2-swagger
result:

```
root@2d426841549e:/var/www/html# npm install magento2-swagger --save
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/www/html/package.json'
/var/www/html
`-- magento2-swagger@0.0.8  

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/www/html/package.json'
npm WARN html No description
npm WARN html No repository field.
npm WARN html No README data
npm WARN html No license field.
```

Comment: I think you have issue in you custom module.

Answer (score 1):

Swagger try to generate documentation from class annotation.

You use array as API type.

It is not support by Magento swagger implementation.

You can try to use anyType as a workaround or create your custom type.

**Reference :**

```
\Magento\Framework\Reflection\TypeProcessor
```

**Allowed base type :**

```
/**#@+
 * Normalized type constants
 */
const NORMALIZED_STRING_TYPE = 'string';
const NORMALIZED_INT_TYPE = 'int';
const NORMALIZED_FLOAT_TYPE = 'float';
const NORMALIZED_DOUBLE_TYPE = 'double';
const NORMALIZED_BOOLEAN_TYPE = 'boolean';
const NORMALIZED_ANY_TYPE = 'anyType';
```

You can also add array type but you need to do some custom development.

If your website is different than default, you will need to change the form URL hidden value to match your website.

Comment: Is there any easy way to find api's location using array type? I can not find it manually :c

Comment: Try to search array[] in API folders ? Did you create custom API ? Do you install custom modules ? Search there.

Comment: Add log inside the error function near `\Magento\Webapi\Model\Config\ClassReflector::extractMethodData` and `\Magento\Webapi\Model\Config\ClassReflector::reflectClassMethods` to log which class is responsible of the error.

Comment: oh crap. There are a lot of array type in Core Magento Api...

Comment: I do not think so! I do not have to change Magento core to make swagger works. Make sure to debug the class, to see exactly what is the class responsible of the error.

Comment: 1. Magento\Store\Api\StoreConfigManagerInterface // after that 2. Magento/Catalog/Api/ProductLinkManagementInterface.php  // after that 3. Magento/Sales/Api/RefundInvoiceInterface.php  and more more O.o

Comment: I do not have any array annotation type in these files. The array type in PHP method is not used by this swagger error. You need to check PHPdoc array type. Try find `@param array[]` or `@return array[]` with `@api` classes.

Comment: Is it resolved on your side ? Do you find the class cause ?

Comment: I don't know what happens, however after remove vendor, var/di, var/generation (etc), and composer install it works fine

Answer (score 1):

For anyone encountering the same issue as I have where the error was: `<message>The "this" class doesn't exist and the namespace must be specified. Verify and try again.</message>` I was only able to find the issue debuggin this file `/vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/TypeProcessor.php` addin the following at around line 224:

```
$typeIs = $returnMetadata['type'];
            if ($typeIs === 'this') {
                // adding my custom logger here:
            $writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/customApi.log');
            $this->myLogger = new \Zend_Log();
            $this->myLogger->addWriter($writer);
                $this->myLogger->info('methodName: '.$methodReflection->getName());
                $this->myLogger->info(print_r($typeIs, true));
            }
```

Only then I was able to find which method was the culprit. Magento should improve this and print more info at this issue on services pages such as this: `https://yourmagento.com/rest/all/schema?services=all`

Answer (score 0):

looks like some of your api declare parameter/return type as `array[]` that not supported by Magento.

Please fix error and swagger will start to work

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

- Delete vendor, delete composer.lock.
- do `composer install`, `setup:upgrade`, `setup:di:compile`, `indexer:reindex`

And it start works

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone running into this and totally at loss which module provider has not read the docs, here are a few tips&tricks.

I was confronted with the very annoying Internal Server Error above (magento 2.4.4) and found in the developer tools the underlying error

The "array" class doesn't exist and the namespace must be specified. Verify and try again.

[image]

This means someone has provided API functionality that returns a mixed or undefined array which is not allowed. In my case it was Addwish_Awext and I found this by adding the following logging to the above mentioned vendor\magento\module-webapi\Model\Config\ClassReflector.php

```
public function __construct(TypeProcessor $typeProcessor)
{
    $this->_typeProcessor = $typeProcessor;
    // adding my custom logger here:
    $writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/customApi.log');
    $this->myLogger = new \Zend_Log();
    $this->myLogger->addWriter($writer);
}
public function extractMethodData(MethodReflection $method)
{
    $methodData = ['documentation' => $this->extractMethodDescription($method), 'interface' => []];
    /** @var \Laminas\Code\Reflection\ParameterReflection $parameter */
    foreach ($method->getParameters() as $parameter) {
        $parameterData = [
            'type' => $this->_typeProcessor->register($this->_typeProcessor->getParamType($parameter)),
            'required' => !$parameter->isOptional(),
            'documentation' => $this->_typeProcessor->getParamDescription($parameter),
        ];
        $methodName = $method->getName();
        $typeIs = $this->_typeProcessor->register($this->_typeProcessor->getParamType($parameter));
        // try to find something that returns array
        $pos = strpos($typeIs, 'array');
        if ($pos !== false) {
            $this->myLogger->info('methodName: '.$methodName);
            $this->myLogger->info(print_r($typeIs, true));
        }
        if ($parameter->isOptional()) {
            $parameterData['default'] = $parameter->getDefaultValue();
        }
        $methodData['interface']['in']['parameters'][$parameter->getName()] = $parameterData;
    }
    $returnType = $this->_typeProcessor->getGetterReturnType($method);
    // try to find something that returns array
    $pos = strpos($returnType['type'], 'array');
    if ($pos !== false) {
        $this->myLogger->info('(getter) methodName:'.$method->getName());
        $this->myLogger->info(print_r($method, true));
    }
    if ($returnType['type'] != 'void' && $returnType['type'] != 'null') {
    ....
```

Opening the CustomApi.log I found:

(getter) methodName: getState
Laminas\Code\Reflection\MethodReflection Object
(
[name] => getState
[class] => Addwish\Awext\Api\Service\StateInterface
)

Disabling the module, clear cache and do a full frontend deploy and... swagger works again.

Comment: this helped me but my issue is `<message>The "this" class doesn't exist and the namespace must be specified. Verify and try again.</message>` Could not find `this` anywhere in the log by the way I've remove if condition so it print everything. I'm not sure where this is coming from any other ideas I can try?

Comment: @JulianoVargas try setting a breakpoint at the try/catch in `\Magento\Framework\Reflection\TypeProcessor::register`. When it triggers, you can find the method name and the class that probably claims `@returns this` in its PHPdoc comment.