# Class "String" does not exist swagger magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am working with swagger api but when hit this url :-

```
http://localhost/magentosetup/swagger
```

I get the error when I am trying to use api please help.  :-

```
500 : {"message":"Class \"String\" does not exist. Please note that namespace must be specified.","trace":"#0 \/mnt\/data\/home\/134855.cloudwaysapps.com\/etfeurwasq\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Reflection\/TypeProcessor.php(212): Magento\\Framework\\Reflection\\TypeProcessor->register('String')\n#1 \/mnt\/data\/home\/134855.cloudwaysapps.com\/etfeurwasq\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Reflection\/TypeProcessor.php(181): Magento\\Framework\\Reflection\\TypeProcessor->_processMethod(Object(Zend\\Code\\Reflection\\MethodReflection),
```

Comment: check this one https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160730/magento-2-1-3-swagger-and-api-error

Answer (score 1):

In my case this error occurred when setting an extension attribute value with a wrong type where type `string` was expected.

Aligning the extension attribute value type with the expected type fixed the issue.